# Search feature for Google Maps having errors (Android Studios)

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

Okay, so currently what I'm doing is trying to add a simple app which reports and locates broken down cars. On the third screen, I have the user enter an Address, click the Search Button, and a small map at the buttom would move to that location once found. If the user is satisfied, he can click the Submit button and process to the next screen...(the submit button isn't finished yet, I just testing the map)

I've followed the steps given by this youtuber [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dr0zEmuDuIk)...and I'd thought I had it all figured out...Yet when I tested my app, I tried typing something simple like New York, and I get a fatal error message...

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.greyknightdante.roadsideassistance, PID: 7950
              java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                  at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4698)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
               Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4693)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610) 
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265) 
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755) 
               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
                  at com.example.greyknightdante.roadsideassistance.MapsActivity.onSearch(MapsActivity.java:45)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4693) 
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610) 
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265) 
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

I am still new to Android Studios and to top it off, I am also currently sick right now and can't think straight with this headache I'm having (from both the cold and this dang app).....I have a week to finish this app, so I'm currently on a rush....

I can't quite figure out whats causing the error and how to fix it...I have a feeling it might be the onClick for my Search Button but I can't be sure...Can someone help me? Any help would be appreciated!

Heres my code for the Java Activity

```
package com.example.greyknightdante.roadsideassistance;

import android.content.Intent;

import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback{

private GoogleMap mMap;
public String problem;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_gps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    //obtain previous data
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    problem = intent.getStringExtra(ReportActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

}

public void onSearch(View view){
    EditText location_input = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.locationInputText);
    String location = location_input.getText().toString();
    List<Address> addressList = null;

    if(location != null || location.equals("")) {
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
        try {
            addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(location, 1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Address address = addressList.get(0);
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(),address.getLongitude());
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Marker"));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    }

}
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}
```

and heres the section of my map and search feature...

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/gpsLayout">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="What is your location?"
        android:id="@+id/locationTextView"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPostalAddress"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/locationInputText"
        android:text=""
        android:hint="Enter Location..."
        android:layout_below="@+id/locationTextView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:textSize="25dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Search"
        android:id="@+id/enterGPSButton"
        android:layout_below="@+id/locationInputText"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="onSearch"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/locationInputText"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
        android:id="@+id/mapLayout">
        <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context="com.example.greyknightdante.roadsideassistance.MapsActivity"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is in this line:

```
 EditText location_input = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.locationInputText);
```

here `Editext` is not attached to `onSearch(View view)`

so change:

```
     EditText location_input;  //declare globally

    @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_gps);
    location_input = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.locationInputText); //initialize here
    }
```

Now in your `onSearch()` method

```
public void onSearch(View view){
String location = location_input.getText().toString();
//rest of the code
}
```

Comment: @RamonChristianBustamante mark the answer as correct if it helps by clicking the tick sign